# How do I use Resolve to permanently extract and save small clips from mov files/

Tags: davinci-resolve

I have hundreds of GBs of movs that I want to get rid of most of the video from each on and then do some editing.
What would be the workflow using Resolve? 
Export as?  or Transcode as?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it right in QuickTime.

- Open the videos in QuickTime
- Edit > Trim
- Save or Export those shorter clips
- Import them into your preferred editor

If you do want to use Resolve:

- Import your clips to your Media Pool
- Click on the Edit tab, select all of your clips in the media pool, drag them to your timeline.  The order of them doesn't matter, if you just want individual clips, neither does having gaps in your timeline.
- Once you have trimmed your clips as desired, go to the Deliver tab
- Make sure to select Individual Clips at the top and adjust your settings as desired [image]
- Select your entire timeline and then add the job to your render queue
- Render

Comment: I installed Quicktime on my Windows 10 computer but it looks like the edit functions are only available on the Pro version. Not sure if Windows 10 runs that, does Windows 10 have any edit feature?

In Resolve I don't have any Apple codec options so I tried H.264 and the file size ends up quadruple the original.

Comment: The render format, codec, settings, etc. you use will all depend on what you intend to do with these videos and your own personal preferences.  Generally speaking, h.264 is a decent tradeoff between bandwidth/quality, but I wouldn't suggest using it for videos that you still plan to edit and work with. @RichardLewandowski